# What is the best design strategy for exposing multiple DataObjects/Methods within the .Net WCF service framework?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm relatively new the world of Microsoft WCF. I have a few questions regarding the best design pattern/method to use to implement one or more services that will address my needs.

I have an existing DataLayer which I would like to push into 1 or more WCF services. The backend database is ORACLE (and I have an entire data access layer which communicates with the correct version of ODAC).

When I look at my existing datalayer, I (more or less) have support for mulitple data objects (classes).

- UserInfo
- UserActivityHistoryAudit
- Evaluations
- EvaluationWorkFlowAndReview
- EvaluationReports

I have several questions involving the best way to implement this in WCF.

1. Is it best to implement this as one service or several services (one which coincides with each data class/functionality)?
2. Ultimately, I would like to share the underlying Data Access layer which communicates with the ORACLE ODAC library.  Is it best to embed this in a shared library, assembly?
3. If I go with multiple services, is it cleaner to hang them all off of the same endpoint?

What is the best strategy to use when designing this?

Thanks,
JohnB

Answer (score 0):

Often times, your business layer will also be implemented on the server.  In such an event, you will simply wrap your business layer.  If you do not have a business layer on the server side, model your service based on the same concept.  You are exposing a set of functionality to target a specific consumer (or set of consumers).  You will generally have one service to present to each consumer (or set of consumers).  With that being said, you do not want one large monolithic service just to cover all of your potential needs.  Break it down into logical areas.

Most of the time, wrapping a single data layer object is too small to wrap by itself.  The exception is if you are simply servicing the data generically to everyone (very common with REST and ODATA services).

===========================

1. Model your services based off of consumption needs.  One service per consumer set.
2. If you will be sharing your data layer across multiple business layers in different binaries, the data layer should exist in its own stand alone library and shared.
3. The endpoint layouts for your services are not generally important as long as you are consistent.  At the end of the day, your consumers will simply copy/paste the endpoint that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to use one service that is WCF Data Service (OData)
here a sample you can download
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WCF-Data-Service-OData-ebb4214a

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Factory and Repository Pattern? Something like this.

> 

```js
`public interface IEmployee
{
    // define your model here (properties, for example)
    string FirstName {get; set;}
    string LastName {get; set;}
}

public interface IEmployeeBizFactory
{
    IEmployee CreateEmployee();
}

public class CustomEmployee : IEmployee
{
    // Implementation here
}

public class CustomEmployeeBizFactory : IEmployeeBizFactory
{
    public IEmployee CreateEmployee()
    {
        return new CustomEmployee();
    }
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider Data Contracts for each of your data objects

[Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

Comment: "Enter link description here"?

Comment: Surprise the link is to Data Contacts.   This got down voted for not having a link description?